# I need fontsize 8.5pt

Tags: fontsize, koma-script

I need \fontsize 8.5pt. I know there are some other questions with a similar question. There I read something about using KOMA-Script, but this does not work for me:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=8.5pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\begin{document}
This is no fontsize 8.5pt.
\end{document}
```

But as you can see (in the 'blue box' below), 8.5pt got substituted by fontsize 8pt. 
How can I avoid this substitution?
[image]

Comment: Try to use a `\fontsize{8.5pt}{10pt}\selectfont` in your document.

Comment: @TeXnician which will be removed at the next `\normalsize` in the doc.

Comment: @daleif Which you could redefine ;)

Comment: @TeXnician which of course is the correct solution, one will need a 8.5pt adjusted/compatible clo file. My point was that just issuing ` \fontsize{8.5pt}{10pt}\selectfont` is a very bad suggestion as it does not solve the OPs problem

Comment: @daleif I know, but unfortunately I forgot to mention the redefinition. Mostly because I don't know if there is a better way.

Comment: @TeXnician have you looked in the KOMA manual for `fontsize=` it does state that you can use any value, which does not seem to correspond to what actually happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53325/discussion-between-texnician-and-daleif).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the Computer Modern fonts definition doesn't specify any font for the 8.5pt size, therefore, the LaTeX engine has to choose the closest available 8pt. But you can use some other font which does. For example, the Latin Modern looks the same and works fine for me.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=8.5pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{helvet}
\begin{document}
This is fontsize 8.5pt.
\end{document}
```

Another approach it to use the `fix-cm` package as suggested by @daleif. You just have to load it before `\documentclass` to prevent the class to load the unfixed font definitions.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[fontsize=8.5pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\begin{document}
This is fontsize 8.5pt.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yuo do not need `lmodern`, `fix-cm` seems to be enough

Comment: Thank you, i've never heard of `fix-cm` before. I've updated the answer.