# Matching a word template's font size and spacing

Tags: fonts, margins, fontsize, line-spacing

I have a MS Word template for a proposal, but as I hate working with Word, I would like to transform it to LaTeX. I've been playing around with the fancy header class, and so far I've managed to get a very nice result. Now I would like to fine tune a few things. One of the requirements from the template is that the font size be 8.5. I found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352900/i-need-fontsize-8-5pt) that describes how to do it, but I don't think I get it right.

So in the preamble I have

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[fontsize=8.5pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
```

but then when I write in the document

```
This is the normal font and  {\fontsize{8.5}{10} \selectfont this is the font when I specify 8.5 }
```

I get

[image]

so clearly I'm not using 8.5 font.
Also, I would like to change the font to a sans serif type, but I don't know how to do that keeping the font 8.5?
Finally, I'm not sure how I can adjust the spacing between components in the page. I'm using the `geometry` package and fancy header, and I'm doing all the adjustment by just looking at it. I was wondering, however, if there's a smarter way to do this?

The MWE is very simple but shows the issue on the font size:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[fontsize=8.5pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}


\begin{document}
    This is the normal font and  {\fontsize{8.5}{10} \selectfont this is the font when I specify 8.5 }
\end{document}
```

Comment: article only accepts a fixed set of font sizes (10, 11, 12 iirc). KOMA has arbitrary font size support and also better options for spacing e.g. of sections etc. To change to sf font you will definitely find an option on this site.

Comment: `extarticle` class allow use 8pt  (but not 8.5pt).